# Javascript doesn't seem to correctly handle hidden elements that are later displayed

Tags: javascript, css

I am having difficulty understanding the following behaviour of Javascript / CSS.

I am attempting to create a modal div which will serve as an enlarged photo from a gallery. I want to display this dead centre on screen. If I define the div as display: none and then change this via Javascript, it doesn't seem to work as I would expect.

I appreciate it would be simpler to just use Example 1 below and it isn't necessary to hide the div first. What I would like to do, however, is define the div in HTML with display: none and then display it later. I don't want to have to create the div with Javascript. The below is simply the easiest way to illustrate the issue.

Example 1 below works as you might expect. Example 2 works only if you comment out the last line which sets the margins. If you do, then the div vanishes.

**Example 1 - Works as expected**

CSS

```
#photoviewdiv{
  position: fixed;
  /*display: none;*/
  width: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

JS

```
var photoviewdiv = document.createElement("div");
photoviewdiv.setAttribute("id", "photoviewdiv");
document.body.appendChild(photoviewdiv);
//photoviewdiv.style.display = "inline";

photoviewdiv.innerHTML = "Hello";
var viewerwidth = photoviewdiv.offsetWidth;
var viewerheight = photoviewdiv.offsetHeight;

photoviewdiv.setAttribute("style",
    "margin-left: -" + viewerwidth/2 +"px; margin-top: -" + viewerheight/2 +"px");
```

**Example 2 - Only works up until set margins - then photoviewdiv disappears**

CSS

```
#photoviewdiv{
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

JS

```
var photoviewdiv = document.createElement("div");
photoviewdiv.setAttribute("id", "photoviewdiv");
document.body.appendChild(photoviewdiv);

photoviewdiv.style.display = "inline";

photoviewdiv.innerHTML = "Hello";
var viewerwidth = photoviewdiv.offsetWidth;
var viewerheight = photoviewdiv.offsetHeight;

photoviewdiv.setAttribute("style",
    "margin-left: -" + viewerwidth/2 +"px; margin-top: -" + viewerheight/2 +"px");
```

Comment: `.style.display:inline` might be causing width issues, try `.style.display:inline-block` or `.style.display: block` instead

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. I tried photoviewdiv.style.display = "block"; and photoviewdiv.style.display = "inline-block";. Neither seemed to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `style.display = inline`, but later removing it when you reduce `style` to just `margin-left` and `margin-top`.  The original `display: none` from the CSS is all that's left.

Include a visible `display` property alongside the margins:

```
photoviewdiv.setAttribute("style",
 "margin-left: -" + viewerwidth/2 + "px; " +
 "margin-top: -" + viewerheight/2 +"px; " +
 "display: block");
```

Alternatively:

```
photoviewdiv.style.display    = "block";

var viewerwidth = photoviewdiv.offsetWidth;
var viewerheight = photoviewdiv.offsetHeight;

photoviewdiv.style.marginLeft = "-" + viewerwidth  / 2 + "px";
photoviewdiv.style.marginTop  = "-" + viewerheight / 2 + "px";
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/HEesj)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. It kind of works, but now the negative margins do not seem to be having any effect. The div is displayed with top left aligned to the centre of the screen as if the negative margins have not been applied. I am using the second bit of code you provided.

Comment: Be sure to take the width/height measurements after setting `display: block`. Updated the example to reflect that.

Comment: Yes! Bingo that was the issue. Thanks so much for that.